# Build a virtual room with ARCore without Unity

Tags: android, arcore

I have searched this site and googled it, with no result.

I need to build an Android app that creates a virtual room, and the user has to search for some items in that virtual room in order to "win the game". The problem is, all I find are tutorials about how to build an Augmented Reality app that places virtual objects in the real world, or tutorials using Unity. I don't want to use Unity. I need to create a full room with its walls, furniture, etc. Anybody can give me some advise on where to start, or where to look at? I can't find anything relatable to what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a ARCore usecase, but rather a VR one. ARCore is meant to place virtual objects in the real world, where a VR solution would allow you to build your own room with objects located within.

Comment: And if the room IS the virtual 3D object? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried something similar, and it is very hard to get walls and ceiling at the right scale in ARCore. It is also hard to add geofencing because you can go through walls in strange ways...